# Performing long multiplication with vectors

Tags: c++

I am writing a file that will take in two lists of coefficients for polynomials and multiply them together to produce a single list of coefficients that represents a new, resultant polynomial.

I have been able to write pretty much all of the code except for the part where I actually multiply them because I am unsure how to do long multiplication in code. By long multiplication I mean how you would do it in grade school where you would multiply digits and add them all up at the end, except instead of digits its coefficient terms, with each coefficient being an entry in a vector.

For example if one vector is (4,0,0,0,0,0,80,3) and the second is (0,7,0,0,4) the resultant vector would be (0,28,0,16,0,0,0,560,21,0,320,12)

Im at a loss for how to make this work, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int up_multiply(std::vector<int> in1, std::vector<int> in2)
{
    std::vector<int> w3; // creates vector of type int for resultant polynomial

    for(int a=0; a<in2.size(); a++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<in1.size(); b++)
        {
            // multiplication will go here
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<w3.size(); i++) // outputs w3
    {
        std::cout<< w3[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Before writing one line of code, you should have this planned out on paper first.  Trying to write code and then muse about what to do next isn't the ideal way to do this assignment.  Anyway, the assignment is actually testing you on whether *you* can come up with a solution (paper first, then code).  It really would be considered cheating if someone were to actually give an answer.

Comment: You've got the framework pretty much set up.  You should probably initialize `w3` with a size.  The you should attempt to solve the problem.  This is not a place where other people do your homework for you.

Comment: Why are you declaring your function to return an int and then return 0? This isn't `main()`.

Comment: In addition to what has been said, why not start out with something simple, like a 3 degree polynomial multiplied by a 2 (or 1) degree polynomial?  If that works, then it should work for any degree polynomial.

Comment: You do it in code exactly like you do it with pencil abd paper. Try explaining long multiplication to a (perhaps imaginary) friend who has no idea. Write down your explanations. *They are code*. You just need to translate it to your programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do your own work and then ask questions, but you have done something, so let's analyze the code you did write thus far:

As mentioned in one comment, there is no reason to return an integer status code.  If you think this operation might succeed or fail, perhaps you would return true or false, but I don't see why you would think that.

Other suggestions were to work out an example.  What is the answer for:

[sorry, LateX does not work here, how do we post an equation?]

```
$$(2x^2 + 3x - 1) (3x^2 + x + 4)$$
```

work out the answer on paper and implement in your loop, you were on the right track there.

If you were to do this for a big polynomial (let's say, 5000 terms) then copying a vector is slow.  So instead of passing in std::vector you should pass by reference: const std::vector& which just passes in the list you have in main and does not copy.

Why use int as the type?  Don't you want to be able to handle polynomials with decimal coefficients, like 2.5x?

How are you going to pass the answer back to the caller?  Perhaps instead of your integer return, you might want to return a polynomial?

Why would you name this routine up_multiply?  Does this imply there is a down_multiply?

This comment is useless:  // creates vector of type int for resultant polynomial
You are making a classic beginner mistake, explaining the language to yourself.
If you called the variable answer or result instead of w3, then this comment would not be useful.

Don't name variables in1, in2 and w3.  That does not describe what they are.  Even a short name like p1, p2 indicates that they are polynomials and mirrors standard mathematical notation for polynomials, and result or answer describes the variable being returned.

Last, don't print out things inside functions that compute answers.  You might want to compute a polynomial (fast) without printing it (slow).  So write one function to compute the polynomial, and another one to print it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
vector<double> multiply(const vector<double>& p1, const vector<double>& p2)
{
    vector<double> result;

    for(int a=0; a<in2.size(); a++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<in1.size(); b++)
        {
            // multiplication will go here
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void print(const vector<double> p) {
  for(int i=0; i < p.size(); i++) {
    cout<< p[i] << " ";
  }
  cout<< '\n';
}
```

Write a main to test your code:

```
int main() {
  vector<double> a = {1, 2, 3};
  vector<double> b = {4, -1, 2};
  vector<double> c = multiply(a,b);
  print(c);
}
```

It seems like you are a beginner, so you might not need to do this, but be aware that in C++ you can overload operators.  So instead of the name multiply you can define it as the operator *

```
  vector<double> c = a * b;
```

All you would need to do is change the name multiply to operator *